# Appian platform on Kubernetes for production?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, appian

The [Appian Release Notes for version 21.4](https://docs.appian.com/suite/help/21.4/Appian_Release_Notes.html) states the following on container-based installation of the Appian platform on a production environment.

> Appian for Docker Containers has been replaced with a new implementation using Kubernetes. We are providing a Kubernetes Operator to manage Appian instances in your own non-production cluster using a single configuration.
>
> This is a preview release of Appian on Kubernetes. *Look for a production-ready version of Appian on Kubernetes in upcoming releases.*

I am desparately waiting for news on that topic, and I do not find any further or more up-to-date information on that issue. **Maybe you can help me to make the last sentence (emphasized by me) of the quote can be made less vague, please?**

Comment: Sorry I can't help but I would ask on Appian community. It happened to me that Appian employees replayed on my question.

Answer (score 1):

As announced at the [Appian 22.1 Webinar](https://community.appian.com/b/product-announcement-webinars/posts/appian-22-1-product-announcement-webinar) by Malcom Ross ([Deputy-CTO of Appian](https://twitter.com/mrappian)), for the upcoming Appian version 22.1 its Kubernetes package is production ready:

[image]